# TFS Lab Management Default Template Build Number

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, lab-management

I am in the process of trying to understand TFS Lab Management but unfortunately do not have an environment for trying it out.

My understanding is that when using Lab Management you use two build templates. A normal build template associated with your solution and a further 'master' template for Lab Management.

I notice in the LabManagementDefault template there is a build number similar to that found in the standard build template. How does the use of these two build numbers differ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not, the lab build takes on the identity of the build that is deployed.